Unexpected JWT alg received, expected RS256, got: HS256
I have an Auth0 tenant which I first configured manually and it worked with my application. Now I have switched to managing it using terraform and since then I get an error when logging in that states
Callback handler failed. CAUSE: unexpected JWT alg received, expected RS256, got: HS256

I have checked the application and the token algorithm is still listed as RS256. Also in the Terraform Config I added this property specifically. What could be the reason the JWT is signed using the wrong algorithm?
This is how the API resource is defined in terraform:
resource "auth0_resource_server" "api" {
  identifier = "my-id"
  name       = "My Name"

  allow_offline_access                            = false
  enforce_policies                                = true
  skip_consent_for_verifiable_first_party_clients = true

  signing_alg            = "RS256"
  signing_secret         = null
  token_dialect          = "access_token_authz"
  token_lifetime         = 86400
  token_lifetime_for_web = 7200
  verification_location  = null
}


I'm not sure enough for this to be an answer, but FWIW I'm interpreting this message as a complaint that the JWT you used has the wrong algorithm, not that the wrong algorithm is selected in the Auth0 configuration. If that were true then you'd need to either reconfigure the system that's issuing the JWT to use RS256, or (if it doesn't support that algorithm) reconfigure the Auth0 settings to accept HS256 instead.

Hi Martin, thank you for your hint. No, the error does come from the client implementation expecting a different token. The token is generated by auth0. But in the mean time we found out, that we had a wrong configuration in another part of auth0. Thanks for bringing it to my attention again, I'll add an answer.

We were missing another part of the configuration. The provided config is only for the api, but the client does also allow to specify the jwt configuration:
resource "auth0_client" "client" {
  # ...

  jwt_configuration {
    alg                 = "RS256"
    # ...
  }
}

This fixes the issue.
